# 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'isin'

Tags: python

I am stuck with what to do right now because I keep getting this error.I have alredy use the fct isin(),
but for now it doesn't work:
CODE:

```
1. from scipy.io import loadmat
2. import pandas as pd
3. data = loadmat('ex3data1.mat')
4. print(data['y'])
5. filtre = data[data['y'].isin([9])]
6. print(data[filtre])
```

OUTPUT ERROR:

```
>>>
[[10]
 [10]
 ...
 [ 9]
 [ 9]]
>>>>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\*temp.py", line 5, in <module>
    filtre = data[data['y'].isin([9])]
AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'isin'
```

I appreciate all the help I can get. Thanks a lot

Comment: What happened when you tried putting `numpy isin` into a search engine? Or copying  and pasting the entire phrase, `'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'isin'`? Stack Overflow is not intended to replace existing tutorials and documentation.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish?  The `data` object (returned by the `loadmat()` method) is a dictionary with one key/value pair for each variable.  You cannot apply a mask to a dictionary the same way you would mask a numpy array (or a pandas series/dataframe).

Comment: `loadmat` returns a dictionary. Were you expecting it to return a Pandas DataFrame? [https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.io.loadmat.html](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.io.loadmat.html)